# Displaying the video in the TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Good afternoon, I will explain the problem in details. I'm connecting the TinyMCE editor version `4.6.4` to my site. It has plugins in the Media plugin through which you can insert media files into the editor.

Thus, I add video to the editor. Actually, you can add a video in different ways, and one of them is to give the editor a direct link, and I do so.

There is a parameter `media_live_embeds` in the initialization of the editor,  which can be inserted into the position `true` or `false`, and if the parameter is inserted into true, then, the added video can be played directly in the editor.

The problem is that if I give a link to a video from my site (`vvv.mp4` example), then, it does not play (as if the parameter is inserted in media_live_embeds: false).

But if for example I add a video link from youtube (example `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6_yRWPd4Yc`) then it works.

Here on the screen there are 2 videos, the first one with youtube link, and the second with a link from the site, the first one is played directly from the editor, and the second one is not.

[image]

What's my mistake? Who had this problem?

Here is the [editor](https://jsfiddle.net/razmikgalstyan/e7x308cf/), you can test yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the property is `media_live_embeds` so this will permit to played directly in the editor embeds media. When you insert a video URL, tinyMce construct embed video code integration :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LIMYj5mpMM4" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when you insert a video from your website without create a url access to content video or from local files, tinyMce will create a html element : `<video><video>`. So you couldn't play it in the editor since it wasn't and embeds media url.